# Last image disappears

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm creating a website using bootstrap carousel and at the last image when it should cycle back to the first, the whole carousel disappears...not at all sure why.

Check out the [staging site](http://opsandss.com/new) for reference.

Comment: Got me stumped. Notice the carousel loops in reverse? 3->2->1->4->3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed off a closing "div" at the end of: "item ad4". Done a bootply and it solves your issue. Added closing div to line 58 of bootply. http://bootply.com/73140

Comment: Oh, would you look at that. Thanks!